# How to deals with big number with PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm building a dashboard on Grafana from Prometheus datasource.

This dashboard deals with filesystem capacity. I'need some PromQL queries to be parametrized with these capacity, which are big numbers:

```
node_filesystem_size{env="dev", mountpoint="/sx/bddv2"} < 100000000000
```

It's quite annoying to deals with all that zero, is there any way to use SI suffixe (G, M, K)?

Comment: you can use binary operations: 100000000000 = 100 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prometheus supports [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for big number. For example, you can write `1e9` instead of `1000000000`:

```
node_filesystem_size{env="dev", mountpoint="/sx/bddv2"} < 100e9
```

P.S. VictoriaMetrics - Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on - additionally supports `K`, `M`, `G` and `T` suffixes (powers or `1000`) alongside `Ki`, `Mi`, `Gi` and `Ti` suffixes (these are powers of `1024`) for numeric constants in its [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query language:

```
node_filesystem_size{env="dev", mountpoint="/sx/bddv2"} < 100G
```